# Removing Alert When Using DeleteFile API

Tags: vb.net, vba, api

I'm writing a VBA application which involves looping a large number of directories recursively. I am using the FindFirstFile API to to achieve this, as it offers a substantial performance boost over the FileSystemObject.

In order to remove the FSO from my code entirely, I need a routine to delete files. This has brought DeleteFile to my attention. Although I have it working - see the below code - it shows an alert to the users, asking if they'd like to delete the file. I need to remove this alert, as is possible with FSO. Application.DisplayAlerts = False does not work in this instance - most likely because it's an API call.

Is there a way to remove the alert?

```
Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hWnd As Long
    wFunc As Long
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAborted As Boolean
    hNameMaps As Long
    sProgress As String
End Type

Private Const FO_DELETE = &H3

 Private Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Long
 Private Declare Function DeleteFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "DeleteFileA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Private Sub TestDelete()
Dim SHDirOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT

With SHDirOp
    .wFunc = FO_DELETE
   '.pFrom is file to be deleted, copied, or moved should be
    .pFrom = "My Path Here"
   'you might also look at adding
End With

'struct (Type) is now properly initialized
'call the function
SHFileOperation SHDirOp

 End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try `Kill "FileName.txt"` it works for me with no alerts, no APIs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several SHFILEOPSTRUCT.fFlags options you'll want to consider.  You are asking for `FOF_NOCONFIRMATION`, &H10.  You probably want some more, like FOF_ALLOWUNDO, FOF_SILENT, FOF_NOERRORUI, it isn't clear from the question.  Check [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).